# Why does Django try the wrong url pattern?

Tags: python, django, url, forms

Django tries the wrong url pattern but I can not find my mistake.

**urls.py**

```
     url(r'^message/(?P<advertisementid>(\d+))/$', chat_view, name="chat_view_with_toid"),
     url(r'^profile/(?P<userid>(\d+))/$', profile_view, name="profile"),
     url(r'^details/(?P<advertisementid>(\d+))/$', details_view, name='details'),
```

**views.py**

```
def details_view(request, advertisementid):
    advertisement_data = Advertisement.objects.get(id=advertisementid)
    return render(request, "details.html", {"advertisement_data": advertisement_data})

def profile_view(request, userid):
    advertisements = Advertisement.objects.filter(user__id=userid)
    return render(request, "profile.html", { 'advertisements': advertisements } )
```

**details.html** (from where I want to resolve to the users profile)

```
<a href="{% url 'profile' userid=advertisement_data.user.id %}" style="text-decoration:none;">
<input type="submit" class="details-btn-profile" value="Profile"></a>

    <a href="{% url 'chat_view_with_toid' advertisementid=advertisement_data.id %}" 
    style="text-decoration:none">
    <input type="submit" class="details-btn-contact" value="Kontakt"></a>
```

**main.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'details' advertisementid=advertisement.id %}">
<img src="{% static advertisement.image.url  %}" alt="Image"/></a>
```

When I click on button `class="details-btn-profile"` Django gives me this error:

> Reverse for 'details' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['details/(?P(\d+))/$']

Why does it resolve to details ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Is there a form around the given HTML code?

Comment: No but <a href should be enough ?

Comment: A form would control the behavior of any submit button inside. I'm not sure what happens if there is no form. There could be an implicit default one resulting into a GET to the same URL and the given error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time, I found my mistake. On profile.html I had this HTML-Code:

```
<a href="{% url 'details' %}" class="announce-hedline"><h3>BMW 320i Limousine</h3></a>
```

So `"{% url 'details' %}"` can not be resolved because of missing the advertisementid which it needs to be resolved.

I searched for mistakes in the wrong place.

Thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 1):

when you click the button you send form where action wrong may be empty attr `action` something like it:

```
<form action="">
```

you need set it:

```
<form action="{% url 'profile' userid=advertisement_data.user.id %}">
           <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^-->
```

or if you want to go link by click the just change `type`

```
 <input type="button" class="details-btn-profile" value="Profile">
    <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^-->
```

Comment: You are right but I really need a form for that ? I did it in another place just with <a href= etc.  .. It should be enough or am I wrong ?

Comment: You are right using button is better than submit, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The url name `chat_view_with_toid` doesn't seem to exist in your urls.py.

Comment: Yeah... although the actual error message suggests there's something else afoot... Doesn't look like the OP has provided it...

Comment: @AaronVisang so where are you using `{% url 'details' ... %}` - we can only see `{% url 'chat_view_with_toid' ... %}` in your template...

Comment: I add it now it was in my main.html